# Запятая перед «и пока я ждал»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, управление, сложное-предложение

*Вчера я отправил ему сообщение и(,) пока ждал ответ(,) выпил чашку кофе.*
Запятая нужна перед "и" или после?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы это предложение оформила так:
*Вчера я отправил ему сообщение и, пока ждал **ответа**, выпил чашку кофе.*

[Пока](https://www.endic.ru/academic/Poka-41327.html) — это временной союз, который употребляется для выражения **одновременности** действия главного и придаточного предложения. Означает: *в то время как; в течение того времени как.*
Придаточные предложения необходимо выделять запятыми.

Возможная сложность здесь в том, что при чтении пауза присутствует не после союза "и", а **перед** ним.
Проблема решается просто: перестановка придаточного невозможна (Вчера я отправил ему сообщение, выпил чашку кофе, и пока ждал ответа). Это означает, что союз "и" относится к главному предложению, а не к придаточному (он соединяет однородные сказуемые *отправил* и *выпил*).

Слово "ответ", считаю, лучше употребить в родительном падеже: *ждал ответа.*
Винительный падеж можно было бы использовать в таком предложении:
*Вчера я отправил **брату** сообщение и, пока ждал **его** ответ, выпил чашку кофе.*

В словаре управления:
[ждать](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

1. **чего** (при сочетании с отвлеченным существительным или конкретным, но употребленным с оттенком неопределенности). *Ждать возможности; Ждать писем; Ждать поезда* (какого-либо).
2. кого-что (при сочетании с одушевленным существительным или неодушевленным, но употребленным с оттенком определенности). *Ждать сестру; Я жду одну женщину* (Т.); *Ждать ежедневную почту; Ждать поезд Симферополь—Москва.*

*Он оставил дверь приоткрытой и, **пока ждал ответа,** слышал, как один из следователей рассказывал...* (Ю Несбе. Леопард); *Я подал условный сигнал и, **пока ждал ответа,** испытал чувство тревоги...* (М. П. Ботин. Мемуары); *Он снова вспомнил Стокгольм, женщину, чье имя он до сих пор не забыл, и, **пока ждал ответа,** представил себе красивый город, построенный на островах, город, где повсюду была вода* (А. Рослунд, Б. Хелльстрем. Возмездие Эдварда Финнигана).